# How to make group clickable?

Tags: javafx

I've got a group which is composed of rectangle nodes. 
They are scattered around the group and a lot of the groups background is visible and unfilled by rectangles.

I have a context menu popup when the rectangle is clicked, and I would like a different context menu to show when the group background is clicked.

I tried

```
Group g = new Group();
g.setOnMouseClicked((e) -> {
    world.show(g, Side.TOP, 0, 0);
});
```

But now when I click on a rectangle both the rectangles context menu shows up as well as the groups context menu.

How could I make it so the group menu shows up only when clicking on the background (where a rectangle is not placed)?

Answer (score 1):

Try to consume the event received to rectangles

```
rect.setOnMouseClicked( e -> {
    world.show(rect, Side.TOP, 0, 0);
    e.consume();
});
```

Comment: I tried that but now the group background is no longer clickable.

Comment: @Mkey, I don't think you can observe the mouse click on group background. Since there is no background at all for a group. Please edit your question to provide an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve of your current use case. Try to use `Pane` in replace of `Group` to see the "real" background.